# Why 0/0 is NaN but 0/0.00 isn't

Tags: c#, datatable, double, decimal, formula

Using `DataTable.Compute`, and have built some cases to test:

```
dt.Compute("0/0", null); //returns NaN when converted to double

dt.Compute("0/0.00", null); //results in DivideByZero exception
```

I have changed my code to handle both. But curious to know what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess, that it happens because literals with decimal points are threated as `System.Decimal` and cause the `DivideByZeroException`

According to [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

> Integer literals [+-]?[0-9]+ are treated as `System.Int32`, `System.Int64`
>   or `System.Double`
>
> Real literals without scientific notation, but with a decimal point,
>   are treated as `System.Decimal`. If the number exceeds the maximum or
>   minimum values supported by `System.Decimal`, then it is parsed as a
>   `System.Double`.

Accroding to [DivideByZeroException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.8)

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to divide an
>   integral or `Decimal` value by zero.

For `System.Double` it returns Nan, because if the operation is a division and the constants are integers it changes to a double result type, according to [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Filter/BinaryNode.cs,a1b76c129906c462) (Thanks @steve16351 for nice found)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but something just doesn't seem right: Documentation states "DataSet will first attempt to parse the number as an Int32. This will not succeed because the number is too large. In this case DataSet will parse the number as an Int64, which will succeed. If the literal was a number larger than the maximum value of an Int64, DataSet will parse the literal using Double." Since `0` does fit Int32, the compute of `"0/0"` should also result in a Division by zero exception, and not in `NaN` which can only be explained of the expression is treated as `System.Double`.

Comment: For `System.Double` the result of a division by zero is not `Infinity`, it's `NaN` (Not A Number)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, in this case it's Nan, I've updated an answer. In general: Dividing a floating-point value by zero doesn't throw an exception; it results in positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number (NaN), according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic.

Comment: True, but that still doesn't explain why `"0/0"` is treated as double instead of int 0 divided by int 0.

Comment: Looking at the [relevant part](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Filter/BinaryNode.cs,a1b76c129906c462), line 1053, of the `DataTable` expression evaluation code, if the operation is a division and the constants are integers it explictly changes to a double result type, with comment "if the operation is a division the result should be at least a double".

Comment: @steve16351 I'm looking the same sources as well:)

Comment: @steve16351 while that provides an explanation, it would be nice to see some explanation in official documentation of this behavior. Otherwise, it's undocumented and as such it's not guaranteed to stay the same in newer releases.